# quantstrat demo luxor.8 error: Error in runSum(x, n) : Invalid 'n'

Tags: r, quantstrat

I installed the latest package today, and ran all the demos up to luxor.8, everything else is good but luxor.8 still has an error as follows:

```
Error in runSum(x, n) : Invalid 'n'
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In beg:(n + beg - 1) :
  numerical expression has 2 elements: only the first used
2: In 1:(n - 1 + NAs) :
  numerical expression has 2 elements: only the first used
3: In beg:(n + beg - 1) :
  numerical expression has 2 elements: only the first used
4: In 1:(n - 1 + NAs) :
  numerical expression has 2 elements: only the first used
5: In beg:(n + beg - 1) :
  numerical expression has 3 elements: only the first used
6: In 1:(n - 1 + NAs) :
  numerical expression has 3 elements: only the first used
7: In `/.default`(runSum(x, n), n) :
  longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length
```

output of `sessionInfo()`:

```
R version 3.2.3 (2015-12-10)
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0 (64-bit)
Running under: OS X 10.11.3 (El Capitan)

locale:
[1] en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/C/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8

attached base packages:
[1] parallel  stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
 [1] doMC_1.3.4                    iterators_1.0.8               quantstrat_0.9.1709           foreach_1.4.3                 dplyr_0.4.3                   blotter_0.9.1695              PerformanceAnalytics_1.4.3541
 [8] FinancialInstrument_1.2.0     quantmod_0.4-5                TTR_0.23-0                    xts_0.9-7                     zoo_1.7-12                   

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] Rcpp_0.12.3       codetools_0.2-14  lattice_0.20-33   assertthat_0.1    grid_3.2.3        R6_2.1.2          DBI_0.3.1         magrittr_1.5      robustbase_0.92-5 tools_3.2.3       DEoptimR_1.0-4    compiler_3.2.3
```

I noticed that this error produced by luxor.8 in the latest package is different from [the error generated in previous version of the package](https://r-forge.r-project.org/tracker/index.php?func=detail&aid=6258&group_id=316&atid=1269). So, I assume this latest version of package has solved the previous error in luxor.8. If so, the error I reported should be trivial, right?

Could anyone give me some advice on the error I reported above? Thanks